# Lyx equations separated by text

Tags: equations, lyx

I have converted a .docx file to Lyx and get the inline equations as

```
$V$, such as that if ${{v}_{i}}\in V$ and ${{v}_{j}}\in V$
```

I wonder if there is a way to convert them to equations in an automatic (not one by one) way.

Comment: Note that a .lyx file is just a text file. If you can program the replace using awk or sed or a Python script, you can do it in the .lyx file. To do that, convert one by hand (in LyX), and compare the "before" .lyx file to the "after" .lyx file. And then automate that conversion with your preferred text-editing tool.